# Buildpack with distroless base image

Tags: buildpack

When I use distroless/base-debian11 for base image everything is fine, but when I run the image return

> ERROR: failed to launch: bash exec: no such file or directory

I use for build `#!/busybox/bash`

How to fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Agreed, need more info. If you could include the output from the buildpacks when you build the image that would be helpful. As well as the buildpacks or builder you're using. If you're building with pack, the full command you're running would be helpful too. Regardless of how you build, running `pack inspect <img>` on the image that gets built and including that information would be helpful too.